# symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 in Xcode 10 (ERROR)

Tags: ios, xcode

I am facing the problem in my ios project. symbols not found for architecture x86_64 in Xcode clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation). I  nuked my xcode and project folder multiple times trying to get around this. I'm stuck. Any ideas? The log is below. I am trying to run a simulator build on Xcode 10.

```
  Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
    "google::LogMessage::LogMessage(char const*, int, int)", referenced from:
        facebook::react::CxxNativeModule::invoke(unsigned int, folly::dynamic&&, int)::$_1::operator()() const in CxxNativeModule.o
        facebook::react::JSException::buildMessage(OpaqueJSContext const*, OpaqueJSValue const*, OpaqueJSString*, char const*) in JSCHelpers.o
        facebook::react::NativeToJsBridge::callFunction(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >&&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >&&, folly::dynamic&&)::$_1::operator()(facebook::react::JSExecutor*) const in NativeToJsBridge.o
        facebook::react::NativeToJsBridge::invokeCallback(double, folly::dynamic&&)::$_2::operator()(facebook::react::JSExecutor*) const in NativeToJsBridge.o
    "double_conversion::DoubleToStringConverter::ToShortestIeeeNumber(double, double_conversion::StringBuilder*, double_conversion::DoubleToStringConverter::DtoaMode) const", referenced from:
        double_conversion::DoubleToStringConverter::ToShortest(double, double_conversion::StringBuilder*) const in CxxNativeModule.o
    "double_conversion::DoubleToStringConverter::ToFixed(double, int, double_conversion::StringBuilder*) const", referenced from:
        std::__1::enable_if<(std::is_floating_point<double>::value) && (IsSomeString<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >::value), void>::type folly::toAppend<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, double>(double, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >*, double_conversion::DoubleToStringConverter::DtoaMode, unsigned int) in CxxNativeModule.o
        std::__1::enable_if<(std::is_floating_point<double>::value) && (IsSomeString<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >::value), void>::type folly::toAppend<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, double>(double, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >*, double_conversion::DoubleToStringConverter::DtoaMode, unsigned int) in JSCExecutor.o
        std::__1::enable_if<(std::is_floating_point<double>::value) && (IsSomeString<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >::value), void>::type folly::toAppend<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, double>(double, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >*, double_conversion::DoubleToStringConverter::DtoaMode, unsigned int) in MethodCall.o
        std::__1::enable_if<(std::is_floating_point<double>::value) && (IsSomeString<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >::value), void>::type folly::toAppend<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, double>(double, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >*, double_conversion::DoubleToStringConverter::DtoaMode, unsigned int) in Value.o
    "double_conversion::DoubleToStringConverter::ToPrecision(double, int, double_conversion::StringBuilder*) const", referenced from:
        std::__1::enable_if<(std::is_floating_point<double>::value) && (IsSomeString<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >::value), void>::type folly::toAppend<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, double>(double, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >*, double_conversion::DoubleToStringConverter::DtoaMode, unsigned int) in CxxNativeModule.o
        std::__1::enable_if<(std::is_floating_point<double>::value) && (IsSomeString<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >::value), void>::type folly::toAppend<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, double>(double, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >*, double_conversion::DoubleToStringConverter::DtoaMode, unsigned int) in JSCExecutor.o
        std::__1::enable_if<(std::is_floating_point<double>::value) && (IsSomeString<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >::value), void>::type folly::toAppend<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, double>(double, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >*, double_conversion::DoubleToStringConverter::DtoaMode, unsigned int) in MethodCall.o
        std::__1::enable_if<(std::is_floating_point<double>::value) && (IsSomeString<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >::value), void>::type folly::toAppend<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, double>(double, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >*, double_conversion::DoubleToStringConverter::DtoaMode, unsigned int) in Value.o
    "google::LogMessageFatal::LogMessageFatal(char const*, int)", referenced from:
        std::__1::enable_if<(std::is_floating_point<double>::value) && (IsSomeString<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >::value), void>::type folly::toAppend<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, double>(double, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >*, double_conversion::DoubleToStringConverter::DtoaMode, unsigned int) in CxxNativeModule.o
        facebook::react::Instance::initializeBridge(std::__1::unique_ptr<facebook::react::InstanceCallback, std::__1::default_delete<facebook::react::InstanceCallback> >, std::__1::shared_ptr<facebook::react::JSExecutorFactory>, std::__1::shared_ptr<facebook::react::MessageQueueThread>, std::__1::shared_ptr<facebook::react::ModuleRegistry>) in Instance.o
        facebook::react::JSBigFileString::fromPath(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)::$_0::operator()() const in JSBigString.o
        facebook::react::JSBigFileString::c_str() const in JSBigString.o
        facebook::react::JSCExecutor::~JSCExecutor() in JSCExecutor.o
        facebook::react::JSCExecutor::callNativeModules(facebook::react::Value&&) in JSCExecutor.o
        std::__1::enable_if<(std::is_floating_point<double>::value) && (IsSomeString<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >::value), void>::type folly::toAppend<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, double>(double, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >*, double_conversion::DoubleToStringConverter::DtoaMode, unsigned int) in JSCExecutor.o
        ...
    "google::LogMessage::stream()", referenced from:
        std::__1::enable_if<(std::is_floating_point<double>::value) && (IsSomeString<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >::value), void>::type folly::toAppend<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, double>(double, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >*, double_conversion::DoubleToStringConverter::DtoaMode, unsigned int) in CxxNativeModule.o
        facebook::react::CxxNativeModule::invoke(unsigned int, folly::dynamic&&, int)::$_1::operator()() const in CxxNativeModule.o
        facebook::react::Instance::initializeBridge(std::__1::unique_ptr<facebook::react::InstanceCallback, std::__1::default_delete<facebook::react::InstanceCallback> >, std::__1::shared_ptr<facebook::react::JSExecutorFactory>, std::__1::shared_ptr<facebook::react::MessageQueueThread>, std::__1::shared_ptr<facebook::react::ModuleRegistry>) in Instance.o
        facebook::react::JSBigFileString::fromPath(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)::$_0::operator()() const in JSBigString.o
        facebook::react::JSBigFileString::c_str() const in JSBigString.o
        facebook::react::JSCExecutor::~JSCExecutor() in JSCExecutor.o
        facebook::react::JSCExecutor::callNativeModules(facebook::react::Value&&) in JSCExecutor.o
        ...
    "google::LogMessage::~LogMessage()", referenced from:
        facebook::react::CxxNativeModule::invoke(unsigned int, folly::dynamic&&, int)::$_1::operator()() const in CxxNativeModule.o
        facebook::react::JSException::buildMessage(OpaqueJSContext const*, OpaqueJSValue const*, OpaqueJSString*, char const*) in JSCHelpers.o
        facebook::react::NativeToJsBridge::callFunction(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >&&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >&&, folly::dynamic&&)::$_1::operator()(facebook::react::JSExecutor*) const in NativeToJsBridge.o
        facebook::react::NativeToJsBridge::invokeCallback(double, folly::dynamic&&)::$_2::operator()(facebook::react::JSExecutor*) const in NativeToJsBridge.o
    "google::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()", referenced from:
        std::__1::enable_if<(std::is_floating_point<double>::value) && (IsSomeString<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >::value), void>::type folly::toAppend<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, double>(double, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >*, double_conversion::DoubleToStringConverter::DtoaMode, unsigned int) in CxxNativeModule.o
        facebook::react::Instance::initializeBridge(std::__1::unique_ptr<facebook::react::InstanceCallback, std::__1::default_delete<facebook::react::InstanceCallback> >, std::__1::shared_ptr<facebook::react::JSExecutorFactory>, std::__1::shared_ptr<facebook::react::MessageQueueThread>, std::__1::shared_ptr<facebook::react::ModuleRegistry>) in Instance.o
        facebook::react::JSBigFileString::fromPath(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)::$_0::operator()() const in JSBigString.o
        facebook::react::JSBigFileString::c_str() const in JSBigString.o
        facebook::react::JSCExecutor::~JSCExecutor() in JSCExecutor.o
        facebook::react::JSCExecutor::callNativeModules(facebook::react::Value&&) in JSCExecutor.o
        std::__1::enable_if<(std::is_floating_point<double>::value) && (IsSomeString<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >::value), void>::type folly::toAppend<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, double>(double, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >*, double_conversion::DoubleToStringConverter::DtoaMode, unsigned int) in JSCExecutor.o
        ...
  ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Looks like you are missing `glog`?

Comment: This could be everything, but i know it usually happens when you try to run a project which has a framework which is only compatible with a real device (no simulator)...

Comment: I'm running into the same issue with a project, glog is a pod in the project, linker can't seem to find it?

Answer (score 1):

Inside pods, under targets, click on React then, build phases > link Binary with libraries add DoubleConversion.Framework and glog.framework and Folly.framework. Whenever you do pod update please make sure these are added under react dependencies then run. [image]

Answer (score 0):

in React.podspec your need change

```
ss.compiler_flags       = folly_compiler_flags
```

to

```
ss.dependency             "DoubleConversion"
ss.dependency             "GLog"
ss.compiler_flags       = folly_compiler_flags
```

3 part

ps: GLog or glog

Answer (score 0):

The solution was so easy when I Read the error message...

Just add x86_64 arch to ur dependency. I haven't it, cause I added React-Native to existed ios app, and it has some diff with the app, which was created with React-Native as default.

```
React-logger -> Build Settings -> Architectures
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is because by running the app on the simulator, You are using any framework, which is built for device support only, and here you are compiling on the simulator.

Answer (score -1):

I am facing the same problem on 12 feb either. So I opened an issue for this problem on [Github](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/23390).

There is a workaround for this problem.

[image]

Manually adding DoubleConversion and glog to Link Binary With Libraries of React framework target in @CocoaPods project.

And this issue fixed in RN 0.58.4