# Symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 in Xcode 13

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, cocoapods

Currently I'm working on integrating the firebase cloud messaging service to a react native mobile application. I followed their [documentation](https://rnfirebase.io/) on firebase integration and edited the pod file to use frameworks.

When using the frameworks. I got an error about transitive dependencies. that's why I had to add `pre install do` and `$static_framework`.

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '11.0'

$RNFirebaseAsStaticFramework = true
target 'P2PMobileApp' do
  use_frameworks!

  $static_framework = ['FlipperKit', 'Flipper', 'Flipper-Folly', 'CocoaAsyncSocket', 'ComponentKit', 'DoubleConversion', 'glog', 'Flipper-PeerTalk', 'Flipper-RSocket', 'Yoga', 'YogaKit', 'CocoaLibEvent', 'OpenSSL-Universal', 'boost-for-react-native']

  pre_install do |installer|
    Pod::Installer::Xcode::TargetValidator.send(:define_method,:verify_no_static_framework_transitive_dependencies) {}
    installer.pod_targets.each do |pod|
      if $static_framework.include?(pod.name)
        def pod.build_type;
          Pod::BuildType.static_library
        end
      end
    end
  end
  config = use_native_modules!

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # to enable hermes on iOS, change `false` to `true` and then install pods
    :hermes_enabled => false
  )

  pod 'RNVectorIcons', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons'

  target 'P2PMobileAppTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable the next line.
  # use_flipper!()

  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(installer)
    __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
  end
end
```

Now I'm having following error when I try to run app with `react-native run-ios`

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x84_64:
  "google::LogMessage::LogMessage(char const*, int, int)", referenced from:
    __react_native_log_default in react_native_log.o
  "google::LogMessageFatal::LogMessageFatal()", referenced from:
    __react_native_log_default in react_native_log.o
...
```

**Note**: I have done my pod installation with `arch -x86_64 pod install` because I'm working on a mac mini with an M1 chip.

I tried to resolve that issue with the following solutions. But none of them worked out

- [Link binaries with xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55883032/8626855)
- [Changing the architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72125848/8626855)
- Change the architecture for pod installation (Then I get the same issue related to arm64)
- Removing **glog** from `$static_framwork` variable (Then the same `Undefined symbols for architecture x84_64:` issue arises for double conversion module)

Still I,m stuck with build fails. Any help on this will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using M1 chip then it can be resolved with below steps:

Go to application > right click on Xcode > Get info > select Open using Rosetta
Restart the system

[image]

The other solution can be adding library

You can add it by:

- Clicking on your project in the upper left of the left pane (the blue
  icon).
- In the middle pane, click on the Build Phases tab.
- Under "Link Binary With Libraries", click on the plus button.
- Find YOUR_FRAMEFOERK.framework from the list and hit Add.

Comment: I was already using **Open with rosetta** option. And Link Binary With library also not possible as YOUR_FRAMEFOERK.framework files are not available

Comment: you can add it from node_modules/yourlibray/yourFramework.framework

Comment: When I do a search for *.framework files in node_modules, It returned none : (

Comment: what is the name of your library which you are tring to ad

Comment: build phases > link Binary with libraries add DoubleConversion.Framework and glog.framework and Folly.framework.

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/32496#issuecomment-1067589704

Comment: DoubleConversion.framework and glog.framework are the libraries that are unavailable as frameworks in my project and need to be added.

I tried the solution in the given link. Still I'm unable to build the project with the error ```Undefined symbols for architecture x84_64:```.